Solution to a system of nonlinear equations with certain conditions
I am working in a model and I found a problem relating a nonlinear system of equations. Let $\mathbf{D}(\mathbf{Q})\in \mathbb{R}^N$ for $\mathbf{Q}\in \mathbb{R}^N$ be a continously differentiable function. Assume there is some vector with positive components $\mathbf{L}\in \mathbb{R}$ such that the following contitions hold.

$\displaystyle\lim_{Q_i\to 0} D_i(\mathbf{Q})=\infty$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{Q_i\to \infty} D_i(\mathbf{Q})=0$ for all $i=1,...,n$.
$\displaystyle\frac{dD_i(\mathbf{Q})}{dQ_i}<0$ and $\displaystyle\frac{dD_i(\mathbf{Q})}{dQ_j}<0$ for all $i,j=1,...,n$.
$\displaystyle\left|\frac{dD_i(\mathbf{Q})}{dQ_i}\right|>\left|\frac{dD_i(\mathbf{Q})}{dQ_j}\right|$ for all $i,j=1,...,n$.

Is it possible to proof from the previous conditions that there exists a unique solution to the system of equations $\mathbf{D}(\mathbf{Q})=\mathbf{L}$?
